# Angular NVD3 inverse Focus bar ticks display order

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

is there a way to set a domain for the focus xAxis in Angular NVD3?
in fact I updated the xDomain for the principal chart to inverse the order but for the focus bar are still not in the same order.
any suggestion?
here is a [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z8sXTk?p=preview) for details.
I tried also `x2Domain:[364,3]` but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Ticks and  use the inverse order.
In fact numbers will be automatically sorted and displayed in only one way but using ticks you can display them in the order that you want.